# Call SignalR Javascript function from modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

My DiaryHub.vb has the following:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs

Namespace UIS

    <HubName("DiaryHub")>
    Public Class DiaryHub
        Inherits Hub

        Public Sub PostDiaryHeadline()
            ' Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients. 
            Clients.All.addNewDiaryHeadlineToPage()
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

My Home/Index window has the following code to initiate/configure SignalR.

```
$(function () {

    // Save the reference to the SignalR hub
    var dHub = $.connection.DiaryHub;

    // Invoke the function to be called back from the server
    // when changes are detected
    // Create a function that the hub can call back to display new diary Headline entry.
    dHub.client.addNewDiaryHeadlineToPage = function () {
        // refresh the Headline Entries to the page.
        outputHLDiaryEntries();
    };

    // Start the SignalR client-side listener
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        // Do here any initialization work you may need
        outputHLDiaryEntries();
    });

})
```

The code works and on launch the Headline diary entries are displayed.

I also have a button that opens a Kendo window as a modal with a form for adding new diary entries using this function:

```
function openAddWindow() {
    var addWindow = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
    addWindow.refresh({
        url: "Home/AddDiaryEntry/"
    });
    addWindow.open();
    addWindow.center();
}
```

I then have the following Javascript in my AddDiaryEntry page:

```
function createDiaryEntry() {

    var validFlag = true;
    var errorMsg = "";

    //Validate New Diary Entry
    // removed for brevity...

    if (validFlag) {
        //data is valid

        //get value of checkbox
        var cbValue = ($("#addNew_dHeadline").is(':checked')) ? true : false;

        //clear error area
        $('#errorArea').html("");

        var response = ''
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/SaveDiaryEntry',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                dDate: $("#addNew_dDate").text(),
                dCreatedBy: $("#addNew_dCreatedBy").text(),
                dName: '@AppShort',
                dTeam: teamValue.value(),
                dType: typeValue.value(),
                dRef: $("#addNew_dREF").val(),
                dHeadline: cbValue,
                dServer: multiSelect.value(),
                dComment: editor.value()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                response = result;
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                response = "err--" + XMLHttpRequest.status + " -- " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText + " -- " + errorThrown;
                alert(response);
            }
        });

        //close window
        var addWindow = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
        addWindow.close();

        //if headline entry call SignalR post function to refresh diary entries
        if (cbValue) {

            // reference to the SignalR hub
            var dHub = $.connection.DiaryHub;
            // function to update all clients
            dHub.client.PostDiaryHeadline(); //THIS IS A FUNCTION IN DiaryHub.vb
        }

    } else {
        //error in data
        var out = '<ul class="error">' + errorMsg + '</ul>';
        // display errors
        $('#errorArea').html(out);
    }

}
```

The code works fine - validates the data, saves data to database. The issue I'm having is when I try to call `dHub.client.PostDiaryHeadline()` to invoke the SignalR function. I get the error: `JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'PostDiaryHeadline'`

How do I call the function? Should I call the function before I close the modal window?

Comment: Would it not be: dHub.server.PostDiaryHeadline(); ?

Comment: @TezWingfield Tried your suggestion and got the exact same error. Object doesn't support property or method

Comment: Let me fix my answer and I'll get back to you.

Comment: My answer edited. Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: @TezWingfield Using your suggestions I've have a solution that  now works without the runtime error. The new diary entry shows up in my list on the home page after the popup has been closed unfortunately other browsers with the app open do not get their diary list refreshed. I think I need to read up more on how SignalR works.... possibly having the popup markup embedded in the parent page rather than a partial view would be better. This way all the javascript would be together. Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see your actually expecting a response rather than a server call.
adding `server` will fire a request.

```
    if (cbValue) {

        // reference to the SignalR hub
        var dHub = $.connection.DiaryHub;
        // function to update all clients
        dHub.server.PostDiaryHeadline(); //THIS IS A FUNCTION IN DiaryHub.vb
    }
```

Your already receiving the response here:

```
dHub.client.addNewDiaryHeadlineToPage = function () {
        // refresh the Headline Entries to the page.
        outputHLDiaryEntries();
    };
```

**//EDIT**

There seems to be slight issues through out, so apart from the above(which needs fixing).

On the hub name (backend) replace with: `<HubName("diaryHub")>`

In your JS replace with: `var dHub = $.connection.diaryHub;`

Finally in your `createDiaryEntry();` body should look like so:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        // Do here any initialization work you may need
     if (cbValue) {
        // reference to the SignalR hub
        var dHub = $.connection.diaryHub;
        // function to update all clients
        dHub.server.postDiaryHeadline(); //THIS IS A FUNCTION IN DiaryHub.vb
      }
    });
```

There are a few SignalR issues but that should get you on the right path.

Most SignalR issues stem from case sensitivity and structuring. All very common.

Should be the last issue, replace with: `dHub.server.postDiaryHeadline();`
lower case "p"